# What does "system requires 8-byte headers" means

Tags: header, system

I saw this www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/481.wrf.html where it says that

```
If your system requires 8-byte headers, please set  wrf_data_header_size = 8
```

Would you please tell me how to know that. Thanks in advance.

More info: I am trying to use spec2006 wrf program, which is 2.1 version of the program. I am not able to run that program, although it compiles with runspec.
Error is

```
At line 6744 of file module_ra_rrtm.fppized.f90 (unit = 10, file = 'RRTM_DATA') 
Fortran runtime error: End of file

*** Miscompare of rsl.out.0000, see /path/rsl.out.0000.mis
'rsl.out.0000' short
 Error: 1x481.wrf
```

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Some weather systems take files in one format, some in another. What does yours want?

Comment: @bmargulies  Regarding your question, I don't know the answer. The error I get: At line 6744 of file module_ra_rrtm.fppized.f90 (unit = 10, file = 'RRTM_DATA')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to add `wrf_data_header_size = 8` in the SPEC CPU configuration file you're using to build/run the WRF benchmarks.

See the `config/Example-linux64-amd64-gcc41.cfg` example configuration file that comes with SPEC CPU2006.